hdf5 not found error message , when trying to install communications package on Octave
I'm using Octave on apple MAC, and getting configure: error: hdf5 not found error message when trying to install package on octave using pkg install -forge communication. Now I can see the hdf5 installed under the homebrew/Celler/ folder. My octave is installed under /opt/homebrew/bin/octave how can I point my octave to find this folder when preforming pkg install ?

It's because hdf5 installed in homebrew folder, so Octave can't read it.
Export hdf5 so Ocatave can locate the HDF5
export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/Celler/hdf5 


Maybe you have different installed hdf5 folder, so make sure put your path not mine


For future reference users looking into this answer. Make sure you put the correct path to your hdf5 folder

I just realized that path, sorry for my mistake. Updated my answer. Thanks!
